# Geography and projection in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, projection, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

I'm looking for an alternative to SqlServer.Types capabilities for .NET Core.
I need methods like Buffer(), Intersects(), Distance() using both geography (on spherical Earth) and geometry objects.

Furthermore, I need to project these objects from/to WebMercator projection.

By now, I've had no luck.
Is there any way I can achieve this result?
It should be just (complex, I know) math, so is it possible that no other libraries are exposing these features?

I can't rely on DB so no PostgreSql nor MS-Sql queries are possible workarounds: just in-app code.